# Manually Authenticate a User with Claims for every request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-identity-3, asp.net-core-2.2

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and ASP.NET Identity on an API.

Is it possible to Manually Authenticate a User with Claims for every request?

I would like to use this during initial development stages ...

Answer (score 1):

For authenticating a user without logging, you could try like:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "edward"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "edward zhou"));
    //add your own claims 
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });            
    return View();
}
```